# Frame object from python API from a specific location

Tags: camera

My ultimate goal is to: from a given location L, update a camera to fill the frame with that object at location O such that the camera center after the re-framing is on the axis OL.

Here are the potential avenues that I tried but fail one way or another.

**bpy.ops.view3d.view_selected**

While this appear to be the obvious solution, unfortunately in this situation, the viewport camera frame the object by changing the *location* of the camera, leaving it outside of OL line.

**Tracking constraint**

While this solves the direction problem, the camera is not moved along the OL axis to properly frame the object.

Basically the two potential solution I found only solve half of the constraint and I can't seem to mix them together.

Thanks for your help